# Can I modify the camera preview screen using zxing intents?

Tags: android, android-activity, zxing

I have an Android application with 3 tabs at the top.

The first tab is "Scan" which is supposed to show the camera so you can scan barcodes.

I'm currently using intents with the zxing library. The problem is the camera preview takes the whole screen.

I want to keep the tabs at the top, even on the camera preview screen.

Is it possible to do that with this setup? Or do I have to include the source code of zxing and modify stuff in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ***might*** be possible by using an [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html). It will allow you to host other Intents with your application.

This [article](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity) here seems to state that it is possible and links to a [project](https://github.com/gpodder/GpodRoid) using this approach.

Code for future proof:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Player").setContent(
        new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Archive").setContent(
        new Intent(this, ArchiveGroup.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Updates").setContent(
        new Intent(this, DownloadList.class)));
```

...

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ArchiveActivity",
    new Intent(this, ArchiveActivity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
setContentView(view);
```

...

```
String album = (String) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ArchiveAlbums.class);
intent.putExtra("album", album);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

View view = ArchiveGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager()
                .startActivity("ShowPodcasts", intent).getDecorView();
ArchiveGroup.group.setContentView(view);
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm or expand upon this? I'm new to Android.

Comment: Create a sample project and test it - it doesn't require too much code or time.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to do that with this setup? `NO` Or do I have to include the source code of zxing and modify stuff in there? `YES` but it is not recommended to do so.

Is it possible to do that with this setup?

Becuase you have not control on Zxing library using this. As through Intent it will launch new Application "Zxing" on which you have no control.